# Linking tables from sql, query yields errors.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linked-list

I have two tables in sql and when I echo them out in php I get a weird result...
The desired effect is to echo out intro from table intro and msg from table messages- then organize them by date.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT intro.user_id, intro.date, intro.message_id, intro.intro FROM intro WHERE user_id = {$uid}
                    UNION SELECT messages.user_id, messages.msg, messages.message_id, messages.date FROM messages
                    ORDER BY date DESC ");




while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  "<p>".getElapsedTime($row['date'])."</p>
  <strong>></strong> <a href=\"outro.php?msg_id=".$row['intro.message_id'].
  "\">".$row['intro'] . "</a><br>";
  }
```

```
Intro table
```

[image]

```
Messages table
```

[image]

[image]

However I'm getting this weird result as displayed above. The top portion that are just dates echoing out is from the table `messages`. I don't know why this is happening nor how to fix it.

Comment: The first table / column definition determines how the columns are going to be called, no matter which columns you select in following UNION'ed results. The second column, called `date` in your resultset, is either the `date` from `intro`, or `mesage` from `messages`. You'd better line up your columns properly.

Comment: how u want to be displayed ?

Comment: I'd like the date to be to the left and the intro.intro and messages.msg to be to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UNION is messed up. Try:

```
SELECT intro.user_id, intro.date, intro.message_id, intro.intro
FROM intro WHERE user_id = {$uid}
UNION
SELECT messages.user_id, messages.date, messages.message_id, messages.msg
FROM messages
ORDER BY date DESC
```